# Unity3D Rotate ground using Acceleration is Shaking

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to roll a ball using gravity. I am also trying to rotate the ground using the accelerometer but the ground is shaky when it rotates. I also can't set a limit on the rotation of the x Axis.

```
void Update()
{
    tilt = new Vector3(Input.acceleration.x, Input.acceleration.y, Mathf.Clamp(Input.acceleration.z,-15,15));
    tilt = Quaternion.Euler(90, 0, 90) * tilt; // Change Rotation according to camera view

    if(tilt.x > 0.05f || tilt.x < -0.05f && tilt.x > -6f || tilt.x < 6f)
    {
        transform.localRotation = new Quaternion(-tilt.x, 0, 0, 3);            
    }

    if (tilt.z < -0.1f || tilt.z >0.1f)
    {
        transform.localRotation = new Quaternion(0, 0, -tilt.z, 3);
    }
}
```

Comment: don't set `localRotation` like you did. calculate the tilt difference per frame and implement speed mechanism

Comment: Which one i need to use for this i was try this with transform.Rotate, them my gameobject will start auto rotatinghow to fix it

Comment: it doesn't matter which rotation method you use, you can use `localRotation` too. The point is you need to change it gradually.

Comment: Can you explain more clearly, Or show me some demo code i was try many ways but not got right result. its always start shaking.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps. This is a simple example of many ways to implement angular velocity.

Please be advised that **Gimbel's lock** effect is not considered in calculations. You might want to restrict the rotation in a certain range. Also you will need a dead zone for delta, e.g. `if(delta < epsilon) delta = 0;`.

```
float speed = 40f;
void Update()
{
    tilt = new Vector3(Input.acceleration.x, Input.acceleration.y, Mathf.Clamp(Input.acceleration.z,-15,15));
    tilt = Quaternion.Euler(90, 0, 90) * tilt; // Change Rotation according to camera view
    if(tilt.x > 0.05f || tilt.x < -0.05f && tilt.x > -6f || tilt.x < 6f)
    {
        var delta = -tilt.x - transform.localRotation.x;
        transform.localRotation += (new Quaternion(delta, 0, 0, 3) * Time.deltaTime * speed);

    }
    if (tilt.z < -0.1f || tilt.z >0.1f)
    {
        var delta = -tilt.z - transform.localRotation.z;
        transform.localRotation += (new Quaternion(0, 0, -tilt.z, 3) * Time.deltaTime * speed);
    }
}
```